# AOSP: Mobile Network for Sony XPERIA Tablet Z

Tags: android, mobile, sony

I've successfully compiled the AOSP 4.3 for the Sony xperia tablet z with LTE (SGP321). Unfortunately, the mobile network is not enabled. I assume some more libraries are needed.

Any Hints?

Regards
Olli

Answer (score 0):

RIL is, as far as I know from other devices, easy to fix. You need to extract proprietary blobs from the stock rom of the Xperia Z, which Sony (or other devs) aren't allowed to share.

Refer to this on how to do it:

[How to extract proprietary blobs for Xperia Z ( Yuga)](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_yuga#Extract_proprietary_blobs)

For this, you need to have the file extract_files.sh in your source. Check if you have it, if not, get it from the CM device tree.